# What is the fastest way to upload the big files to the server

Tags: file-upload

I have got dedicated server and file about 4 GB to upload on the server. What is the fastest and most save way to upload that file to the server?

Comment: Have you considered FTP?

Comment: Yes, I considered FTP, but problem is when connection is interrupted while uploading then must start the process again.

Answer (score 0):

FTP may create issues if the connection will be broken.
SFTP will have the same issue as well.
Do you have your own computer available through internet public IP as well?
In that case you may try to set up a simple HTTP server (if you have Windows - just set up the IIS) and then use some download manager on dedicated server (depends from OS) to download the file through HTTP (it can use multiple streams for that) or do this through torrent.
There're trackers, like http://openbittorrent.com/, which will allow you to keep the file on your computer and then use some torrent client to upload the file to the dedicated server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what OS your remote server is running but I would use wget it has a --continue from the man page:

```
--continue
Continue getting a partially-downloaded file.  This is useful when
you want to finish up a download started by a previous instance of
Wget, or by another program.  For instance:

               wget -c ftp://sunsite.doc.ic.ac.uk/ls-lR.Z

If there is a file named ls-lR.Z in the current directory, Wget
will assume that it is the first portion of the remote file, and
will ask the server to continue the retrieval from an offset equal
to the length of the local file.
```

wget binaries are available for GNU/Linux / Windows / MacOSX / dos:

http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions?action=show&redirect=Faq#download